# Inconsistent results between predict() and predict_proba() usin scikit-learn's multi-class text classification packages

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I am working on a multi-class text classification problem that has to provide the top 5 matches as opposed to just the best match. Therefore, “success” is defined as at least one of the top 5 matches being a correct classification.  The algorithm must achieve at least a 95% success rate rate given how we have defined success above. We will of course train our model on a subset of the data and test on the remaining subset in order to validate the success of our model.

I have been using python’s scikit-learn’s predict_proba() function in order to select the top 5 matches and calculating the success rates below using a custom script which seems to run fine on my sample data, however, I noticed that the top 5 rate of success was less than that from the top 1 success rate using .predict() on my own custom data, which is mathematically impossible. This is because the top result will automatically be included in the top 5 results, the success rate must therefore be, at the very least, equal to the top 1 success rate if not more. In order to trouble shoot, I am comparing the top 1 success rate using predict() vs predict_proba() to make sure they are equal, and making sure that the success rate on the top 5 is greater than the top 1.

I have set up the script below to walk you through my logic to see if am making an incorrect assumption somewhere, or if there might a problem with my data that needs to be fixed. I am testing many classifiers and features, but just for the sake of simplicity you will see that I am just using count vectors as features and Logistic Regression as the classifier since I do not believe (to my knowledge, that this is part of the issue). 
I would very much appreciate any insight that anyone may have to explain why I am finding this discrepancy.

Code:

```
# Set up environment
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics, model_selection
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Read in data and do just a bit of preprocessing

# User's Location of git repository
Git_Location = 'C:/Documents'

# Set Data Location:
data = Git_Location + 'Data.csv'

# load the data
df = pd.read_csv(data,low_memory=False,thousands=',', encoding='latin-1')
df = df[['CODE','Description']] #select only these columns
df = df.rename(index=float, columns={"CODE": "label", "Description": "text"})

#Convert label to float so you don't need to encode for processing later on
df['label']=df['label'].str.replace('-', '',regex=True, case = False).str.strip()
df['label'].astype('float64', raise_on_error = True)

# drop any labels with count LT 500 to build a strong model and make our testing run faster -- we will get more data later
df = df.groupby('label').filter(lambda x : len(x)>500)

#split data into testing and training
train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = model_selection.train_test_split(df.text, df.label,test_size=0.33, random_state=6,stratify=df.label)

# Other examples online use the following data types... we will do the same to remain consistent
train_y_npar = pd.Series(train_y).values
train_x_list = pd.Series.tolist(train_x)
valid_x_list = pd.Series.tolist(valid_x)

# cast validation datasets to dataframes to allow to merging later on
valid_x_df = pd.DataFrame(valid_x)
valid_y_df = pd.DataFrame(valid_y)


# Extracting features from data
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train_x_list)
X_test_counts = count_vect.transform(valid_x_list)

# Define the model training and validation function
def TV_model(classifier, feature_vector_train, label, feature_vector_valid, valid_y, valid_x, is_neural_net=False):

    # fit the training dataset on the classifier
    classifier.fit(feature_vector_train, label)

    # predict the top n labels on validation dataset
    n = 5
    #classifier.probability = True
    probas = classifier.predict_proba(feature_vector_valid)
    predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)

    #Identify the indexes of the top predictions
    top_n_predictions = np.argsort(probas, axis = 1)[:,-n:]

    #then find the associated SOC code for each prediction
    top_class = classifier.classes_[top_n_predictions]

    #cast to a new dataframe
    top_class_df = pd.DataFrame(data=top_class)

    #merge it up with the validation labels and descriptions
    results = pd.merge(valid_y, valid_x, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    results = pd.merge(results, top_class_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)


    top5_conditions = [
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[0]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[1]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[2]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[3]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[4])]
    top5_choices = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    #Top 1 Result
    #top1_conditions = [(results['0_x'] == results[4])]
    top1_conditions = [(results.iloc[:,0] == results[4])]
    top1_choices = [1]

    # Create the success columns
    results['Top 5 Successes'] = np.select(top5_conditions, top5_choices, default=0)
    results['Top 1 Successes'] = np.select(top1_conditions, top1_choices, default=0)

    print("Are Top 5 Results greater than Top 1 Result?: ", (sum(results['Top 5 Successes'])/results.shape[0])>(metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y, predictions)))
   print("Are Top 1 Results equal from predict() and predict_proba()?: ", (sum(results['Top 1 Successes'])/results.shape[0])==(metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y, predictions)))

    print(" ")
    print("Details: ")
    print("Top 5 Accuracy Rate (predict_proba)= ", sum(results['Top 5 Successes'])/results.shape[0])
    print("Top 1 Accuracy Rate (predict_proba)= ", sum(results['Top 1 Successes'])/results.shape[0])
    print("Top 1 Accuracy Rate = (predict)=", metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y, predictions))
```

**Example of Output using scikit learn’s built in twentynewsgroups dataset (this is my goal):** 
Note: I ran this exact code on another dataset and was able to produce these results which tells me that the function and it's dependencies work therefore the issue must be in the data somehow.

```
Are Top 5 Results greater than Top 1 Result?:  True 
Are Top 1 Results equal from predict() and predict_proba()?:  True
```

**Details:**

```
Top 5 Accuracy Rate (predict_proba)=  0.9583112055231015 
Top 1 Accuracy Rate (predict_proba)=  0.8069569835369091 
Top 1 Accuracy Rate = (predict)= 0.8069569835369091
```

Now run on my data:

```
TV_model(LogisticRegression(), X_train_counts, train_y_npar, X_test_counts, valid_y_df, valid_x_df)
```

**Output:**

```
Are Top 5 Results greater than Top 1 Result?:  False 
Are Top 1 Results equal from predict() and predict_proba()?:  False
```

**Details:**

- Top 5 Accuracy Rate (predict_proba)=  0.6581632653061225
- Top 1 Accuracy Rate (predict_proba)=  0.2010204081632653
- Top 1 Accuracy Rate = (predict)= 0.8091187478734263

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as why [a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Comment: Thanks! Just shortened it up a bit.... as much as I could anyway.

Comment: Hi @RomualdM. Great thought but because the top_n_predictions array is sorted in descending order, the last value is the highest probability. I did rerun the script with this change just to make sure and the Are Top 1 Results equal from predict() and predict_proba()?: QA changed to False on the data that IS working.

Comment: Whoops, sorry for the mistake, I am deleting my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Found the solution! Apparently the index is reset at some point. So all I needed to do was reset the validation dataset index after the test and training split.

Updated code:

```
# Set up environment
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics, model_selection
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Read in data and do just a bit of preprocessing

# User's Location of git repository
Git_Location = 'C:/Documents'

# Set Data Location:
data = Git_Location + 'Data.csv'

# load the data
df = pd.read_csv(data,low_memory=False,thousands=',', encoding='latin-1')
df = df[['CODE','Description']] #select only these columns
df = df.rename(index=float, columns={"CODE": "label", "Description": "text"})

#Convert label to float so you don't need to encode for processing later on
df['label']=df['label'].str.replace('-', '',regex=True, case = False).str.strip()
df['label'].astype('float64', raise_on_error = True)

# drop any labels with count LT 500 to build a strong model and make our testing run faster -- we will get more data later
df = df.groupby('label').filter(lambda x : len(x)>500)

#split data into testing and training
train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = model_selection.train_test_split(df.text, df.label,test_size=0.33, random_state=6,stratify=df.label)

#reset the index 
valid_y = valid_y.reset_index(drop=True)
valid_x = valid_x.reset_index(drop=True)

# cast validation datasets to dataframes to allow to merging later on
valid_x_df = pd.DataFrame(valid_x)
valid_y_df = pd.DataFrame(valid_y)


# Extracting features from data
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train_x_list)
X_test_counts = count_vect.transform(valid_x_list)

# Define the model training and validation function
def TV_model(classifier, feature_vector_train, label, feature_vector_valid, valid_y, valid_x, is_neural_net=False):

    # fit the training dataset on the classifier
    classifier.fit(feature_vector_train, label)

    # predict the top n labels on validation dataset
    n = 5
    #classifier.probability = True
    probas = classifier.predict_proba(feature_vector_valid)
    predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)

    #Identify the indexes of the top predictions
    top_n_predictions = np.argsort(probas, axis = 1)[:,-n:]

    #then find the associated SOC code for each prediction
    top_class = classifier.classes_[top_n_predictions]

    #cast to a new dataframe
    top_class_df = pd.DataFrame(data=top_class)

    #merge it up with the validation labels and descriptions
    results = pd.merge(valid_y, valid_x, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    results = pd.merge(results, top_class_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)


    top5_conditions = [
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[0]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[1]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[2]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[3]),
        (results.iloc[:,0] == results[4])]
    top5_choices = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    #Top 1 Result
    #top1_conditions = [(results['0_x'] == results[4])]
    top1_conditions = [(results.iloc[:,0] == results[4])]
    top1_choices = [1]

    # Create the success columns
    results['Top 5 Successes'] = np.select(top5_conditions, top5_choices, default=0)
    results['Top 1 Successes'] = np.select(top1_conditions, top1_choices, default=0)

    print("Are Top 5 Results greater than Top 1 Result?: ", (sum(results['Top 5 Successes'])/results.shape[0])>(metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y, predictions)))
   print("Are Top 1 Results equal from predict() and predict_proba()?: ", (sum(results['Top 1 Successes'])/results.shape[0])==(metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y, predictions)))

    print(" ")
    print("Details: ")
    print("Top 5 Accuracy Rate (predict_proba)= ", sum(results['Top 5 Successes'])/results.shape[0])
    print("Top 1 Accuracy Rate (predict_proba)= ", sum(results['Top 1 Successes'])/results.shape[0])
    print("Top 1 Accuracy Rate = (predict)=", metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y, predictions))
```

Comment: Note: the original code listed in the question will in fact work if your validation data set has a traditional index from 0 to n. It will only malfunction if you filter it or re order the dataset in anyway, like deriving it from a test/validation split function used above or if you filter out null values for example. This is why we need to reset the index beginning from 0.